# How to return only specific meta_key values and not all for a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Many thanks for your help; I have a custom post type that has 40 fields.  The  `osm_geometry`  fied is required, however, after that I want to specify which fields to return.  I do not want all 40 fields returned unless only/just `osm_geometry`  is provided.  For example, if  `name`  were mentioned in key then would return  `osm_geomtry`  and `name` .  I see lots of example to select where a `meta_key` equals a value but no example how to filter which fields are returned/selected.  Any help appreciated.

Here is my route:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
    register_rest_route('fs/v1', '/fs_ski_resort/', array(
            'methods'   => 'GET',
            'callback'  => 'fs_ski_resort_data',
            'args'      =>  array(
                    'osm_geometry' => array(
                            'required' => true,
                            'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                                    if ( !empty($param) ){
                                        return TRUE;
                                    } else {
                                        return new WP_Error( 'no_osm_geometry', 'osm_geometry cannot be blank', array( 'status' => 404 ) );
                                    }
                            }
                        )
                ) 
        )
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to filter them in your `fs_ski_resort_data` function. Maybe the filtering example in `prefix_get_colors()` here can help?

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#arguments